# Docker push fails after multiple retries on a specific layer

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to push my own Docker image for an Angular 5 project that I've built. My docker image extends the well known `node:carbon` image and runs the following commands:

```
FROM node:carbon

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install --no-optional

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The `package.json` file has the following content:

```
{
  "name": "turist-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.3.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.1.5",
    "angular-l10n": "^4.1.2",
    "angular2-notifications": "^0.9.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.11.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-auth": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^2.0.3",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "hads": "^1.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

After I've built my image I want to push it to my docker repository. But although I've tried at least 5 times to execute the `docker push` command, every time it fails with the error `file integrity checksum failed for`. It is not always the same file that fails the integrity check and I also didn't notice any timeout behaviour or something similar.

What I have noticed is that the one layer (always the same) fails being pushed and it restarts 5-6 times unsuccessful:

```
cc19355015b5: Pushing [=======>    ]  98.66MB/653.4MB
```

and than

```
cc19355015b5: Pushing [=======>    ]  Retrying in 5 seconds
```

Comment: try `docker history <imagename>` you can see what that layer does and maybe you can change that layer.

Comment: the layer under discussion does not appear in the list there... LE: also all the other layers have CREATED timestamp from two days ago, when I've tried the last time

Comment: have you tried to remove, rebuild and push yet?

Comment: @ajankuv, yes I completly removed the image, the repository on docker hub and also built node_modules again, just to check if everything runs ok.

Comment: Does the docker reg name already exist? I have seen it bug out before on this for some reason.  Try pushing to a new one to see if that works for whatever reason.

Comment: @ajankuv, i've tried pushing it to a new registry name and it worked. don't know if it was now an coincidence or maybe this really was the issue.

Comment: I think it may be a glitch, I read something the other day about this hopefully if it is it gets fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today, then I found a typo in my ECR location, once it is corrected, the push succeeded immediately, so I believe Docker just doesn't tell you that it can't find the ECR repo and stuck in retrying.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to reduce the amount of data that are sent at a time to the registry, by breaking up the layers or using a tool like [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) that falls back to sending 1MB chunks by default if larger chunks don't succeed at first.

The steps are:

1. Download [regctl](https://github.com/regclient/regclient)
2. Save the image as a tar file
3. Push it to the registry using `regctl`

```
curl -L https://github.com/regclient/regclient/releases/latest/download/regctl-linux-amd64 > regctl
chmod 755 regctl
docker save <imagename> > image.tar
./regctl image import <imagename> image.tar -v debug
```

The chunk size can be configured. See this answer for [more in-depth details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74000290/5896674).