# 2022: docker push fails after multiple retries on a specific layer

Tags: docker, push, dockerhub

So stuck again unable to push an image fully to docker hub. I've experienced this in the past, and having it on a loop eventually succeeds, but it's a very annoying process when need to share an image in a timely manner to students.

- `docker login` succeeds
- `docker push` has some layers done, some done after a few retries, and some are existing already so are reused
- then there is always this one layer (each time not necessarily the same when a new image is built) that gets stuck in a retry loop

It looks like something like this:

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/s4lab/gipsy-json-u18]
e17debe53e58: Pushing [==================================================>]  239.7MB/239.7MB
ebe677197a5c: Layer already exists 
962812a24e35: Layer already exists 
37850ad767c2: Layer already exists 
0269df6e94f5: Layer already exists 
e722d396f503: Layer already exists 
write tcp 10.0.2.15:52930->34.205.13.154:443: write: connection reset by peer
The push refers to repository [docker.io/s4lab/gipsy-json-u18]
e17debe53e58: Retrying in 7 seconds 
ebe677197a5c: Layer already exists 
962812a24e35: Layer already exists 
37850ad767c2: Layer already exists 
0269df6e94f5: Layer already exists 
e722d396f503: Layer already exists
```

Each attempt the destination IP address/end point changes.

In the log it's always something along these lines:

```
Oct 07 17:56:02 ub18 dockerd[1254]: time="2022-10-07T17:56:02.418642397-04:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for push after error: write tcp 10.0.2.15:57000->3.216.34.172:443: use of closed network connection"
Oct 07 17:56:03 ub18 dockerd[1254]: time="2022-10-07T17:56:03.550102562-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed, retrying: write tcp 10.0.2.15:57026->3.216.34.172:443: use of closed network connection"
Oct 07 17:56:09 ub18 dockerd[1254]: time="2022-10-07T17:56:09.259048555-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed, retrying: write tcp 10.0.2.15:52918->34.205.13.154:443: use of closed network connection"
Oct 07 17:56:27 ub18 dockerd[1254]: time="2022-10-07T17:56:27.499017532-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed, retrying: write tcp 10.0.2.15:52922->34.205.13.154:443: use of closed network connection"
Oct 07 17:56:48 ub18 dockerd[1254]: time="2022-10-07T17:56:48.198701189-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed, retrying: write tcp 10.0.2.15:52926->34.205.13.154:443: use of closed network connection"
Oct 07 17:57:12 ub18 dockerd[1254]: time="2022-10-07T17:57:12.688987070-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed: write tcp 10.0.2.15:52930->34.205.13.154:443: write: connection reset by peer"
Oct 07 17:57:12 ub18 dockerd[1254]: time="2022-10-07T17:57:12.693009463-04:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for push after error: write tcp 10.0.2.15:52930->34.205.13.154:443: write: connection reset by peer"
Oct 07 17:57:14 ub18 dockerd[1254]: time="2022-10-07T17:57:14.146027151-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed, retrying: write tcp 10.0.2.15:37338->44.205.64.79:443: write: broken pipe"
Oct 07 17:57:20 ub18 dockerd[1254]: time="2022-10-07T17:57:20.589127385-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed, retrying: write tcp 10.0.2.15:37344->44.205.64.79:443: use of closed network connection"
```

This is on:

```
# uname -a
Linux ub18 5.4.0-70-generic #78~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 14:10:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.8
 Git commit:        20.10.7-0ubuntu5~18.04.3
 Built:             Mon Nov  1 01:04:14 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.8
  Git commit:       20.10.7-0ubuntu5~18.04.3
  Built:            Fri Oct 22 00:57:37 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.5.5-0ubuntu3~18.04.2
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.1-0ubuntu2~18.04.1
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

These related questions/answers do not help:

- [Docker push fails after multiple retries on a specific layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793592/docker-push-fails-after-multiple-retries-on-a-specific-layer)
- [Docker push, repeats pushing a layer for ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690046/docker-push-repeats-pushing-a-layer-for-ever)
- different issues over GitHub and elsewhere talking about private and ECR repos, etc. not really applicable

So what is a more reliable / robust solution in 2022 to get past this problem? It seems arbitrary and hard to troubleshoot unless I am missing something. This is especially annoying as I was able to push without issues in the past from the same environment.

Comment: The `connection reset by peer` and `use of closed network connection` issues suggest a network connectivity problem; not something programming-related, and not something where the solution will change at the end of the year.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker push fails after multiple retries on a specific layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793592/docker-push-fails-after-multiple-retries-on-a-specific-layer)

Comment: @KenWhite - as I linked above I looked at those and it does not solve my issue.

Comment: @DavidMaze - certainly not a network issue on my side. I have a 2GBps uplink from a university network. Docker and Docker Hub have been changing as well as their client and server distribution, and their registry APIs. So I am not in agreement with you on this.

Comment: General suggestion, change `COPY file.tgz . / RUN tar xzf file.tgz && rm file.tgz` to `ADD file.tgz .` That will shave off 400MB from your 1GB image. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Comment: Do you have the ability to run some debugging between the build and push? In other words, is this happening on a machine were you can test it now, or is this an ephemeral CI environment and you're looking for general advice?

Comment: Thanks @BMitch, this has already been done. The actual image compressed is about 400+MB. I now use just the latest commit of the repo without history and clean up the artifacts.

Comment: @BMitch -- for your 2nd question: it's a machine I can test on, it's a VM on my machine where I build things, so yes I can insert any debug instrumentation as needed

Comment: If you want to try a science experiment, save the image to a tar with `docker save $image >file.tar`. Then try to push it with regctl (https://github.com/regclient/regclient/, I recommend the binary over the image to match docker's login) using debugging with `regctl image import $image file.tar -v debug`. The debugging will throw a lot of logs that might give you an idea of what's broken.

Comment: @BMitch -- so I've tried your science experiment... Before I got to it though my original image managed to get uploaded to dockerhub in a repeat while loop. Desperate I also created one in ghcr.io and it was also failing a layer, a different one. So I tried your `regctl` with, lots of nice debug output, but it simply ... worked. Very slow, but it pushed the image it seems. Go figure! Thanks for the tip I will have a look more into your tool and maybe use it as a default solution...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248648/discussion-between-bmitch-and-serguei).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be network related. Something on your network is corrupting or dropping the connection. My assumption from that comes from the regctl debug logs showing that it switched to a chunked upload with patch requests. That only happens when the connection is dropped on the normal push. The lack of other errors during the chunked upload rules out anything corrupting the digest on your host.

The default chunk size in regctl is 1MB. That results in a lot of connections for large images that will be slow, but more reliable on flaky networks. You can adjust the chunk size, to improve the speed, with a registry set command, e.g.:

```
regctl registry set --blob-chunk 20971520 --blob-max 104857600 docker.io
```

makes the chunk size 20MB, and automatically uses a chunked upload instead of trying a normal push for any layer over 100MB, when pushing to Docker Hub (docker.io).

Then to use regctl for the push instead of docker, the following can be done:

```bash
docker save $image >file.tar
regctl image import $image file.tar -v info
```

Similarly, if you build your image with buildx, including multi-platform images that you can't store in the docker engine (yet), you can export directly to an OCI Layout that can be imported with the same command:

```bash
docker buildx build -o "type=oci,dest=file.tar" .
regctl image import $image file.tar -v info
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [regclient/regctl](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/).

Comment: This is the 2022 solution I was looking for :) It should be helpful in general to anyone with slow or unreliable networks. I hope it's not my University's side as we have a decent uplink and other things don't seem to have issues and a while repeat loop managed to push my image to DockerHub eventually, but this is a surefire solution it seems. Please update your answer if you can with the info from the earlier comments about `docker save` and `rectl image import` as it may help others looking for this.